# How to develop SNMP agent application in android (Is snmp4j available for android .?)?

Tags: android, snmp, snmp4j

I want to develop a SNMP agent application for my android stack, which should update the status of the devices/resources to a server via MIB. I

Answer (score 1):

SNMP4J and SNMP4J-Agent 2.x do not need to be ported to Android. It can be used directly by importing the JARs into your applications "libs" folder.

Answer (score 0):

SNMP4J was ported to android - see the link https://market.android.com/details?id=cmv.android.snmp&feature=search_result

Comment: aTJ: I wonder if you decided to use this library or chose a different path. Give me some feedback, please.